# I cannot change the "buyTickets" variable after user inputs wrong variable type

Tags: python

```
while buyTickets != int:
    try:
        buyTickets = int(input("{}, how many tickets do you want to buy: ".format(userName)))
        while buyTickets == 0:
            print("You must buy atleast 1 ticket to continue")
            buyTickets = input("{}, how many tickets do you want to buy: ".format(userName))
        ticketCal(buyTickets)
    except ValueError:
        print("Unauthorized Value")
        passe here
```

This is how I'm trying to cycle the code until it's fixed. I have another buyTickets value at top that allows me to get into the code.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, and especially don't post *links* to images of your code. Just include the code itself in the question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Your code is not that huge - do make the effort to include it, as text (not image), in the question. Also, include some context. The first line in you code checks a condition on a variable that has not been initialized. Finally, comparing a variable to the `int` object does not test if it is an integer value, but rather if its value is the object the is the type `int` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try substitute this line of code :

```
while buyTickets != int:
```

with :

```
while type(buyTickets) is not int :
```

EDIT : changed my solution with a pythonical one.

Credits to Amitai Irron (see the comments discussion)

Comment: I prefer the (in my view) more Pythonic conditoin `type(buyTickets) is not int`. Also, a more robust (though usually unnecessary) test would be `isinstance(buyTickets, int)`

Comment: Indeed, what you mentioned is way more pythonical :).
Another robust solution could be : pass None to buyTickets in the except flow, and then in the while condition check if is not None. Obviously would be necessary declare buyTickets  as None :)